# pandas dataframe taking a long time to put in one row

Tags: python, pandas, flask

Everything works, but the last method takes forever (over 1.5 seconds) The dataframe is empty, populated with around 20 columns. The rest of the methods take under .5 seconds.  I would think it wouldn't take so long for a pandas dataframe to create a new row with a given index and populate it with fields.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from flask import request

@app.route('/post/listing')

def post_listing():

    jsondict=json.loads(request.args.get('detail'))

    parse_result,id=parseSleepingBagDetail(jsondict)

    sleepingbag_detail=pd.Series(parse_result)

    existing_pandas_dataframe.loc[id]=listing_detail
```

Comment: Are you adding one row at a time? This will be horribly inefficient, any reason you don't just load the json and create a df: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-json-reader and http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html#pandas.read_json

Comment: OK will do.  I didn't realize that this will be inefficient until I saw it. The reason is that I also have a get/api where I can pull from the same dataframe.  I think it would be cool to have a process where every so often I can write the dataframe additions to a csv. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although possible, adding to a dataframe like this isn't a good/efficient way to go.

I would create and maintain a dict and then batch convert it to a dataframe like this

```
d = {'A': [1,3,5,2], 'B' : [3,3,7,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df

    A   B
0   1   3
1   3   3
2   5   7
3   2   8
```